# Unable to install mysql2 gem OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems, mysql2

I'm new with RoR and I'm trying to install Mysql2 -v '0.3.11'.
I have OS X Mountain Lion, rails 3.2.6  ,ruby 1.9.3.

Below is the error I get.  I looked everywhere and didn't find anything.

```
$gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/curiosity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling client.c
In file included from client.c:1:
In file included from ./mysql2_ext.h:8:
In file included from /Users/curiosity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32:
/Users/curiosity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:105:37:     error: 'ruby_check_sizeof_long' declared as an array with a negative size
typedef char ruby_check_sizeof_long[SIZEOF_LONG == sizeof(long) ? 1 : -1];
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/curiosity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.0.0/ruby/config.h:24:21: note: expanded from macro 'SIZEOF_LONG'
#define SIZEOF_LONG 8
                ^
In file included from client.c:1:
In file included from ./mysql2_ext.h:8:
In file included from /Users/curiosity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32:
/Users/curiosity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:109:38: error: 'ruby_check_sizeof_voidp' declared as an array with a negative size
typedef char ruby_check_sizeof_voidp[SIZEOF_VOIDP == sizeof(void*) ? 1 : -1];
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/curiosity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.0.0/ruby/config.h:28:22: note: expanded from macro 'SIZEOF_VOIDP'
#define SIZEOF_VOIDP 8
                 ^
In file included from client.c:1:
In file included from ./mysql2_ext.h:8:
In file included from /Users/curiosity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32:
In file included from /Users/curiosity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:1377:
In file included from /Users/curiosity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:34:
/Users/curiosity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/st.h:67:45: error: 'st_check_for_sizeof_st_index_t' declared as an array with a negative size
typedef char st_check_for_sizeof_st_index_t[SIZEOF_VOIDP == (int)sizeof(st_index_t) ? 1 : -1];
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/curiosity/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.0.0/ruby/config.h:28:22: note: expanded from macro 'SIZEOF_VOIDP'
#define SIZEOF_VOIDP 8
                 ^
3 errors generated.
make: *** [client.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/curiosity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mysql2-0.3.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/curiosity/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 27):

You're using RVM instead of the Ruby that comes with 10.8. Good. Now, stop using the MySQL that comes with 10.8.

Install and update **[Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)**. Now run

```
brew install mysql
```

Use the `/Gemfile` in your project to install the `mysql2` gem. Add

```
gem "mysql2"
```

to your `/Gemfile`. Then update your application with Bundler by running

```
bundle install
```

Let the package managers *(Homebrew and Bundler)* work for you.

This should fix the issues you're having.

Comment: If you're going to down-vote, please explain why so my answer can be improved.

Comment: The command brew install worked, however, rvm exec bundle install did not. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Francisco does running `bundle install` directly work for you? I haven't used rvm in a long time, it seems the `rvm exec` or `rvm do` are no longer present. Feel free to post a more appropriate edit to the question with what *did* work for you.

Comment: Sure. The command `brew install mysql` worked, and so did `bundle install`. With these steps I could successfully install mysql2

Answer (score 0):

As [Deefour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/605707/deefour) said, I had to use RVM. Answer goes to him, I just couldn't comment on his answer. +1

But `rvm exec bundle install` gave me an error:

`rvm do bundle install` was removed, use `rvm 1.9.2,1.9.3 do bundle install` or `rvm all do bundle install` instead.

I used
`sudo rvm all do bundle install`
and it all went flawlessly from then on.

Answer (score 0):

I too get same type of error in mac10.10 and used below commands that work for me:

1. Install and upgrade Homebrew using:

   brew install mysql
2. run Install Mysql gem file using:

   gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11'
3. Run bundle install