# Bundle Install wont install mysql2 gem with Ruby 1.9.3, Rails3 and Mac Mountain Lion

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, osx-mountain-lion

I am unable to run Ruby on Rails bundle install with Ruby 1.9.3 and Mountain Lion.  It will not install the MySql2 gem.  I have installed Ruby on Rails about 10 times on a mac OS X Lion, so I am very familiar with the steps, but am unable to get the MySQL gem into install.  This is the error I get.  Thanks in advance.

```
    Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

            /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
    checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
    checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
    checking for mysql.h... yes
    checking for errmsg.h... yes
    checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
    creating Makefile

    make
    compiling client.c
    In file included from client.c:1:
    In file included from ./mysql2_ext.h:8:
    In file included from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32:
    /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:105:37: error: 'ruby_check_sizeof_long' declared as an array with a negative size
    typedef char ruby_check_sizeof_long[SIZEOF_LONG == sizeof(long) ? 1 : -1];
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.0/ruby/config.h:24:21: note: expanded from macro 'SIZEOF_LONG'
    #define SIZEOF_LONG 8
                        ^
    In file included from client.c:1:
    In file included from ./mysql2_ext.h:8:
    In file included from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32:
    /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:109:38: error: 'ruby_check_sizeof_voidp' declared as an array with a negative size
    typedef char ruby_check_sizeof_voidp[SIZEOF_VOIDP == sizeof(void*) ? 1 : -1];
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.0/ruby/config.h:28:22: note: expanded from macro 'SIZEOF_VOIDP'
    #define SIZEOF_VOIDP 8
                         ^
    In file included from client.c:1:
    In file included from ./mysql2_ext.h:8:
    In file included from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32:
    In file included from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:1382:
    In file included from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:34:
    /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/st.h:67:45: error: 'st_check_for_sizeof_st_index_t' declared as an array with a negative size
    typedef char st_check_for_sizeof_st_index_t[SIZEOF_VOIDP == (int)sizeof(st_index_t) ? 1 : -1];
                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.0/ruby/config.h:28:22: note: expanded from macro 'SIZEOF_VOIDP'
    #define SIZEOF_VOIDP 8
                         ^
    3 errors generated.
    make: *** [client.o] Error 1


    Gem files will remain installed in /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/mysql2-0.3.11 for inspection.
    Results logged to /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
    An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.11), and Bundler cannot continue.
    Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I have tried bundle install --path mysql and bundle install --system and neither worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guy had the same problem : [Unable to install mysql2 gem OS X Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945425/unable-to-install-mysql2-gem-os-x-mountain-lion)

Are you using the brew version of mysql?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using rvm, and possibly added mysql2 outside of rvm, try these steps: Confirm that your Gemfile says:

> gem 'mysql2'

or for Rails2.x:

> gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.2.11'

then:

```
    $ cd RAILS_ROOT $ gem uninstall mysql2

    Select gem to uninstall:
     1. mysql2-0.2.11
     2. mysql2-0.3.6
     3. All versions
    > 3 # select "All versions" 
$ rvm gemset install mysql2
 $ bundle install
```

Now rails should start properly.

Comment: I did install mysql before installing RVM, but those did not work for me. Thanks

Comment: It breaks with the same error when doing "rvm gemset install mysql2".
"ruby/config.h:28:22: note: expanded from macro 'SIZEOF_VOIDP'
#define SIZEOF_VOIDP 8"

Answer (score 1):

1) first install homebrew from terminal :
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"

2) Install mysql :  "brew install mysql"
3) Install mtsql2 : "gem install mysql2"

It should work.