# How to install mysql2 Ruby Gem on Mountain Lion without having MySQL installed

Tags: mysql, ruby, rubygems, osx-mountain-lion

I want to connect to MySQL remotely, so I don't need to install MySQL on my mac.

On linux it's possible by installing 2-3 libraries (libmysqlclient-dev etc.), I don't know how to do the same on mac.

- Unfortunately, the tutorials i found mention installing mysql.

  - [Unable to install mysql2 gem OS X Mountain Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945425/unable-to-install-mysql2-gem-os-x-mountain-lion/)
  - http://www.creativereason.com/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-mountain-lio.html/
  - http://madebyhoundstooth.com/blog/install-mysql-on-mountain-lion-with-homebrew/
  - http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/installing-ruby-rails-and-mysql-on-os-x-lion/
  - [libmysqlclient15-dev on macs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857861/libmysqlclient15-dev-on-macs)

there's an approach stated here : [libmysqlclient15-dev on macs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857861/libmysqlclient15-dev-on-macs)

> Blockquote
>   fink install mysql-unified-dev to get essentially the same thing as asking for libmysqlclient15-dev on a Debian or Ubuntu type system.

This approach needs further modifications of library path's, But I need a single command to go, yeah I'm that lazy! :-)

Comment: I think this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857861/libmysqlclient15-dev-on-macs

Comment: I should install fink, get libraries, change their path, a lot of work to do :-)
Thanks,
I've seen that before, but I need a more straight way :-D

Comment: As you wish ;) Just don't forget that you should also get include files to build mysql2 gem.

Comment: which MySQL version does ruby use(gem install mysql2)? 5.x.x or 6.x.x?!

Comment: I'm not at my work computer right now. But I think it uses version that is installed on the system. In your case it could be versions of installed libraries. The next question should be: would it work correctly with the mysql server.