# I can't run "bundle update" because of "mysql2" gem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gemfile

I have this in the Gemfile:

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

But when I run **bundle update**, I get this error message:

```
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.16), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.16'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I've tried to move this into the production section, like this:

```
group :production do
  gem 'mysql2'
end
```

But after running **bundle update**, the result is the same. This section is processed only in the production mode, or not?

How to get rid of this error message on localhost?

**EDIT: The whole error message:**

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/radek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/radek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/ruby
/Users/radek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:381:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/radek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:506:in `try_cpp'
    from /Users/radek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:931:in `block in have_header'
    from /Users/radek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:790:in `block in checking_for'
    from /Users/radek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /Users/radek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/radek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:284:in `block in postpone'
    from /Users/radek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:254:in `open'
    from /Users/radek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:280:in `postpone'
    from /Users/radek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:789:in `checking_for'
    from /Users/radek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/mkmf.rb:930:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:9:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/radek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/mysql2-0.3.16 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/radek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.16), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.16'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Thank you

Comment: I believe that is the `full error message`.Please post the `full error message` when you run `bundle update`.

Comment: did you make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.16'` succeeds before bundling?

Comment: I posted the whole error output

Comment: Hmm,That makes sense.On which machine you are working? **`Ubuntu or Mac or Windows`**

Comment: Is the `mysql2 gem` already installed in your machine?

Comment: **bundle show mysql2** -> **Could not find gem 'mysql2 (= 0.3.16) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.**

Comment: The error message says: "You have to install development tools first." Have you done that?

Comment: Are you using **`homebrew`**?

Comment: Did my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 26):

On Ubuntu, run

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Or, if you use MariaDB, run

```
sudo apt-get install libmariadbclient-dev
```

Comment: This worked like a charm for me, thanks! I`ve tried to install redmine-2.5-stable.

Comment: This Works for me! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Looks like there is no `mysql2 gem` installed in your machine.As you are using `Mac OSX`,you should be installing `mysql2 gem` like this

```
gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/opt/mysql/
```

If the above command did't work,try like this

```
sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

And after try

```
bundle install
```

This should fix the error.

**[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167598/mysql-install-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)**

Comment: `brew install mysql` will not install mysql2 gem

Comment: @SergioTulentsev What about this then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11945425/unable-to-install-mysql2-gem-os-x-mountain-lion

Comment: That one will not install the _gem_ too. It will install something else.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes!If it doesn't install `mysql2 gem`,what else it install?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev My appologies!

Comment: I keep getting this error /Users/Ben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.  Any help possible what to check, I have tried many things suggested, it can't seem to build mysql2 or find these dev tools it needs.  Is it possible my mysql setup just doestn' have them

Comment: I had an old mysql installation from home-brew lying around.  I ran `brew update` then `brew upgrade mysql` and then was able to get mysql2 to install using your first suggestion.  Thanks!

Comment: I keep coming back to this great answer.  I finally realized I could add this to my bundle configuration by running `bundle config build.mysql2 --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/opt/mysql/`.  This stores it in the bundle config file at ~/.bundle/config for the next time I have to install the mysql gem with bundler.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in Gemfile:-

```
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.16'
```

Then:-

```
bundle install
```

After that try:-

```
bundle update
```

Answer (score 1):

I just installed mysql via `$ brew install mysql` and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up with a near-identical error message from attempting to build on a machine without `gcc-c++` installed; `mkmf` is failing to compile a simple c program because the compiler flat out isn't there.

If you're on CentOS, you want `sudo yum install gcc-c++`. On Ubuntu, it's `sudo apt-get install g++`. It's a little disappointing that old versions of `ruby-devel` don't have a dependency on `g++`.