# Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 5.5.37 but the client library is 5.6.25

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-migrations, ubuntu-15.04

I upgraded my Ubuntu from 2014.04 to 2015.04 and now `bundle exec rake db:migrate` returns an error:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
rake aborted!
Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 5.5.37 but the client library is 5.6.25.
/home/nico/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `require'
/home/nico/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/mysql2-0.2.11/lib/mysql2.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nico/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/home/nico/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/nico/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/home/nico/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
/home/nico/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/home/nico/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/home/nico/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
/home/nico/myapp/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nico/myapp/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/nico/myapp/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nico/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/home/nico/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/home/nico/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:583:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/nico/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:89:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/nico/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/nico/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `load_rakefile'
/home/nico/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:72:in `block in run'
/home/nico/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/nico/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/home/nico/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nico/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/nico/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362@global/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/home/nico/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/nico/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
```

How to solve this problem?
I would rather avoid changing server-side versions.

The answers at [I can't run "bundle update" because of "mysql2" gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009416/i-cant-run-bundle-update-because-of-mysql2-gem) do not solve the problem.

Local versions:

- gem 2.4.8
- Rails 3.0.19
- mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.25

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running these commands solved the problem:

```
gem uninstall mysql2
bundle install
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and the accepted answer didn't work for me, most likely because I used capistrano, which installs all gems into a per-app shared directory.

```
bundle show mysql2
```

(run in your app's folder) will show you where mysql is installed. Then delete that as well as the the specification.

```
rm -rf /path/to/application/shared/bundle/ruby/<version>/gems/mysql2-<version>
rm /path/to/application/shared/bundle/ruby/<version>/specifications/mysql2-<version>.gemspec
```

should do the trick. Alternatively just delete the complete bundle/* and reinstall everything.